# searching a file in linux

Tags: regex, linux, search, find

I want to find in the system a file, and I know part name of it. How could I do that?
I tried unsuccessfully the command:

```
find / "*partname*"
```

The problem is probably very easy however I cannot find a decent tutorial on searching files in linux. Please tell me what command solves my problem and if you know a good tutorial so that I can understand how to use various parameters for searching, post a link. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
find / -type f -name '*partname*'
```

If you know for sure that the file is in the root filesystem, then you should probably use `-xdev` too, to stop `find` from traversing other filesystem's directories:

```
find / -xdev -type f -name '*partname*'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is older than one day, your chances are high, that it is indexed by the update daemon, and can be found much more quickly with

```
locate partname
```

The exhaustive search with find:

```
find / -type f -name '*partname*'
```

will find freshest files too, but take longer, because it is exhaustive.

Comment: Take care that the files wouldn't be found if there are created or moved after the last `updatedb` *(that udpates the slocate database)*. Note too that `locate` returns not only files that contains the needle, but all paths that contain the needle.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: That's why I wrote 'older than one day'.

Comment: ok thank you, but what is the conventional way to find the file in any situation, on the same day for example?

Comment: What heemayl wrote, but this is an exhaustive search over the whole filesystem.